# in iOS how to reopen application when application is in background state?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to reopen the app from background mode in some way? 
For example, if the app in background is checking any other application is open on device it will automatically go to foreground?

Application purpose is - If user is driving and wants to open sms or any other app, my app will reopen from background

If not, can i display a message and play sound for the user to request app reopen?

Comment: no, it's not possible. You should look into notifications / push notifications.

Comment: You should learn about [inter-app communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot your own app from background. If you want to open the other application like FB, twitter etc, then you can use Location service to monitor app stats and using URL schema, you can launch the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and shouldn't. I can only imagine the unholy mess of several apps attempting to go back to the foreground.

You can do what Google Maps does and use either push or local notifications to let the user know they can go back to the app since interacting with either of the notifications will open the app back up. Note that spamming local notifications will be throttled by the iOS, and should not be abused.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, It is not possible to launch other application from background with the help of our application. But you can build two own app. You can write functionality in one app and launch our own other app with the main app. In this way you can reach on your requirement.